# How can I get rid of space between <div>s?

Tags: html, css

I want one `<div>` to be on the top, three for in the middle in a row and one on the bottom without remaining spaces. And I cannot remove the space between the middle `<div>`s and the bottom one.

[image]

The height of the top and the bottom ones is 15%; while the middle ones have 70%. And the bottom one is slightly out of `.container`.

This is `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is css style.

```
    #wrap{
        width: 90%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 4px solid black;}

    .container{
        width: 93.75%;
        height: 492px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 4px solid black;}

    .container div{
        /*display: block;*/
        height: 100%;}

    .container div:first-child{
        height: 15%;
        background: #003153;}

    .container div:first-child +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #c33;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #2dcc70;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #e75d5d;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div +div +div{
        /*display: block;*/
        height: 15%;
        background: #003153;}
```

Do I have to deal with this by modifying `display:` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` with `display: inline-block`. Default value is `baseline`.

From [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align):

> **`baseline`**: Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent.

```css
#wrap{
  width: 90%;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid black;}

.container{
  width: 93.75%;
  height: 492px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 4px solid black;}

.container div{
  /*display: block;*/
  height: 100%;}

.container div:first-child{
  height: 15%;
  background: #003153;}

.container div:first-child +div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333333333333333%;
  height: 70%;
  background: #c33;
}

.container div:first-child +div +div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333333333333333%;
  height: 70%;
  background: #2dcc70;}

.container div:first-child +div +div +div{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 33.33333333333333333%;
  height: 70%;
  background: #e75d5d;}

.container div:first-child +div +div +div +div{
  /*display: block;*/
  height: 15%;
  background: #003153;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code-

```css
      #wrap{
        width: 90%;
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 4px solid black;}

    .container{
        width: 93.75%;
        height: 492px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border: 4px solid black;}

    .container div{
      vertical-align: top;
        /*display: block;*/
        height: 100%;}

    .container div:first-child{
        height: 15%;
        background: #003153;}

    .container div:first-child +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #c33;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #2dcc70;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div +div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 33.33333333333333333%;
        height: 70%;
        background: #e75d5d;}

    .container div:first-child +div +div +div +div{
        /*display: block;*/
        height: 15%;
        background: #003153;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```